# Obsidian Plugin: SetCursorPosition

Tags: typescript, markdown, obsidian

I want to programmatically open a file (via my obsidian plugin) and jump to a specific cursor position. I have tried the following code, it seems that not much is missing:

```
const editor = this.app.workspace.getActiveViewOfType(MarkdownView).editor;
editor.setSelection(cursor);
editor.focus()
```

I have tried to add `this.app.workspace.updateOptions()`, `editor.refresh()` - but nothing helped - the file is opened but the cursor is always at the start, instead of at the correct cursor position